# How do I handle http 302 redirect from .net remoting?

Tags: .net, http, remoting, http-status-code-302

I need to be able to distinguish http 302 redirects from my code that use .net remoting.

In order to connect to the appropriate url we try them in order until one works.  In most environments the first url correctly fails with a System.Net.WebException with a status of 
WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure.
For Customers that use OpenDNS, however this comes back as a HTTP 302 response that redirects to their Guide page.  Because I am using .net Remoting the redirect is ignored, and the error I recieve is a System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException that is only distinguishable by its message "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."

Here's the opendns http response:
    HTTP/1.0 302 Found
    Location: http://guide.opendns.com/?url=demonstration.totallyinvalidexceptonmynetwork.com%2Fi%2Fdo%2Fnot%2Fexist.html
    Content-type: text/html
    Content-Length: 0
    Connection: close
    Date: Thu, 28 May 2009 20:46:26 GMT
    Server: OpenDNS Guide

Answer (score 0):

I assume that to post the request you are using the `HttpWebRequest` object. Then you can recieve the response in the `HttpWebResponse` object like bellow. 
Then you can check the `response.StatusCode` property. If it is 302 then perform your logic.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
   //your code here
}
```

Update: If you are using `System.Net.Webclient` then you can use the you can use its `ResponseHeaders` property. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx) is how you can use it.

Comment: .net remoting doesn't expose the HttpWebRequest or WebClient or any related classes. The calling code sees a proxy object that looks like the type that's being called on the server. (Yeah, I know this was 2 years ago)